# Linked keys in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to make, say `foo` and `bar` reference to the same object. This is the expected output:

```py
# note that variable d is a dictionary
# d["foo"] and d["bar"] are both have a value of "hello"
print(d["foo"])
print(d["bar"])
d["foo"] = "world"
print(d["foo"])
print(d["bar"])
```

However, this shows:

```
hello
hello
world
hello
```

which is excepted.

But I want the output to be:

```
hello
hello
world
world
```

(note the last line is `world` not `hello`)

Please help.

Comment: strings are immutable, you cannot modify them so upon `d["foo"] = "world"` you create a new object

Comment: How about working on the dictionary part? Say both keys (`foo` and `bar`) refer to the same object

Comment: I added an example

Comment: @mozway One could also implement a custom dict that scans all items on `__setitem__` and changes all keys which are equal to the new value...

Comment: @mozway Also, `d["foo"] = "world"` _may_ create a new object, but it can also reuse another `"world"` if it's been interned or occurs in the module. Not that that matters since it's immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not possible, you would need to use an object that it mutable (e.g. a list):

```
d = {}
d['foo'] = ['hello']
d['bar'] = d['foo']

print(d['bar'])

d['foo'][0] = 'world'
print(d['bar'])
```

output:

```
['hello']
['world']
```